# Get row corresponding to a max count in a Group By

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table of sales broken down into two categories: ZIP Code and Service Type

```
ZIPCode  ServiceID  SalePrice
  47103          1      10.43
  47103          2       8.41
  41703          2      52.12
  41703          2      13.31
  69047          1       5.23
  69047          1      14.62
  69047          2      51.62
  90210          2      85.31
```

I'd like to transform this into a table that provides, for every ZIP Code, the Service ID with the most sales, and the number of said sales:

```
ZIPCode  ServiceID  NumSales
  47103          2         3
  69047          1         2
  90210          2         1
```

I think I can figure out a way to do this using joins and multiple queries to the table, but is there a way I can just run a `GROUP BY` on ZIP Code and retrieve the Service ID that corresponds to the highest `COUNT`?

I'm running Microsoft SQL Server, by the way.

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13128296/sql-query-need-order-by-count-most-must-be-on-top-the-rest-follows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select zipcode, serviceid, sum(sales) as sales
             row_number() over (partition by zipcode order by sum(sales) desc) as seqnum
      from t
      group by zipcode, serviceid
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

If you want ties, then use `rank()` or `dense_rank()` instead of `row_number()`.